# Calling Web API from code and website

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api

First off, I'm using **C# 4.0** as my coding language. I believe I saw some answers where 4.5 has introduced some methods that could make this a lot easier, but it's not my call to change frameworks.

I'm creating an MVC4 WebApi that will be consumed by both websites and C# code (in another project). Typically when calling this from JavaScript, I'd do it like so:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'text',
    url: '//localhost:56814/corporations/1/divisions',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {"Divisions":[{"Name":"In Store"},{"Name":"Online"}]}
}).done(function (msg) {
    alert(msg);
}).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
    alert('Request failed: ' + textStatus);
});
```

Then in my server side code, I would just have my model as a parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Divisions(int id, DivisionCollectionModel model) {

}
```

That model would be defined as such:

```
public class DivisionCollectionModel {
    public IEnumerable<DivisionModel> Divisions { get; set; }
}

public class DivisionModel {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now when I tried to test calling this method from my code, the only way I could find to get the call to work was like this:

```
public static void TestWebApiPost() {
    var divs = new DivisionCollectionModel {
        Divisions = new DivisionModel[] {
            new DivisionModel {
                Name = "In Store"
            },
            new DivisionModel {
                Name = "Online"
            }
        }
    };

    using (var client = new HttpClient()) {
        var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(divs);
        var response = client.PostAsync("http://localhost:56814/corporations/1/divisions", new StringContent(content)).Result;
        Console.WriteLine(response.ToString());
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, that was unable to find the URL as the content of my message was a string instead of the object.

> Is there a method call, or version of `HttpContent` that I'm missing here in how I'm sending the data over that would allow me to send it as an object instead of a string?

I reworked the Api method above to accept `HttpRequestMessage` as the second parameter, figuring this would allow me to use `request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result` to get the object from the request. This worked great for calling it from a C# client. However, when I tried to call it using a JavaScript object, I got the following as my `Result`:

```
"Divisions%5B0%5D%5BName%5D=In+Store&Divisions%5B1%5D%5BName%5D=Online"
```

I tried running that through `System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()` and `System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode()`, but both did nothing to change the encoding done on that string.

**Update**
I realized after writing this that the string that I'm trying to convert is a Url, not an Html string. I then tried using `System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode()`, and that gave me this:

```
"Divisions[0][Name]=In Store&Divisions[1][Name]=Online"
```

Unfortunately, that also throws an exception when trying to run it through `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DivisionCollectionModel>()`.

**Clearer problem set**
I think that it would be better to fix the way that the call is made from the C# client so that I don't have to parse the `HttpRequestMessage`, and allow the Controller to do that "heavy lifting" for me. However, if there is not a way to send my data over as an `object` instead of a `string` in C# 4.0, then the easiest solution would be to just have the JavaScript client send over a string instead of an object.

Am I missing something in my C# client code?

Comment: You did not provide the code for the JavaScript client.

Comment: In response to your updated code, you can't deserialize `Divisions[0][Name]=In Store&Divisions[1][Name]=Online` with Json.NET because that's not valid JSON. If you want the server to return JSON, then in your request header set the `accept` value to `application/json`.

Comment: I updated the JavaScript to pass that as the accept parameter, but it did not change how the object was pulled from the `HttpRequestMessage`. I will update again with a clearer question.

Comment: You're making a lot of updates to your question, which makes it seem like you have posted a bad question. Your question should be clear, showing all relevant code and explaining exactly what your problem is. Also, you seem to be confused on how data is exchanged between servers and clients. You might read into JSON, XML etc, then learn at what point the tools you're using converts them between formats and native objects.

Comment: I do know all of that information. I know how the MVC Controller structure takes all of that information, and processes it into the two types of Action method signatures that I posted in my question.

Comment: Then go learn it. Read a book or work through tutorials on Web API.

Comment: My first edit was because I posted my question too quickly, and thought of another way to try and force it to do what I wanted (though I knew it probably wouldn't work). The second update was because you wanted me to provide something simple and easy to assume as it was not a part of the problem set. My last update was trying to make my problem clearer as it seems as though you were unable to understand what I was trying to achieve (which is understandable as my head was spinning some).

Comment: You do know "I **do** know all of that information" means? I have read several books on the subject, all of which go into details on how those inner workings actually accomplish their tasks, and ways to (inadvisably) create your own ways to do the same. If you don't want to try and help anymore, that's fine. If you want to vote to close because you're no longer willing to help, that's your prerogative. But you're now becoming insulting and impossible to converse with.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. That all points to the fact that you need to stop and put some thought into your question *before* you post. It's extremely difficult to answer a moving target, especially when it lacks a clear problem statement.

Comment: Which it now has. The update you requested was inconsequential, so irrelevant to your point of making it a moving target. My last update was trying to keep it from being a moving target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I found what I was missing with the C# client in 4.0 to get this to send over as a JSON object. This is the updated client:

```
public static void TestWebApiPost() {
    var divs = new DivisionCollectionModel {
        Divisions = new DivisionModel[] {
            new DivisionModel {
                Name = "In Store"
            },
            new DivisionModel {
                Name = "Online"
            }
        }
    };

    using (var client = new HttpClient()) {
        var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(divs);
        var response = client.PostAsync("http://localhost:56814/corporations/1/divisions", 
                new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;
        Console.WriteLine(response.ToString());
    }
}
```

Using the `StringContent` overload that adds in the Encoding, and media type will have it send over as a JSON object. With those changes in place, you can now successfully utilize the same parameter signature that requires just your Model in your WebApi action method.

Answer (score 1):

Change ajax data type
    dataType: 'json',

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not help. I think the better way to attack this is to try and fix the way that the C# code is trying to converse with the API.